# Signing email with MailSystem.NET generates invalid signature

Tags: c#, mailsystem.net

I am trying to sign and send an email with `MailSystem.NET`.

The mail is sent with a signature but the receiving email clients won't accept the signature

Gmail error:

> The sender does not match the digital signature.

Thunderbird error:

> The signature does not match the message contents correctly

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(
      @"sender.pfx",
      "password",
      X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    var signer = new CmsSigner(cert)
    {
        IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly
    };

    Message message = new Message();
    message.From.Email = "sender@gmail.com";
    message.To.Add("me@gmail.com");
    message.Subject = "Subject";
    message.BodyHtml.Text = "Html";
    message.BodyText.Text = "Plain Text";
    message.BuildMimePartTree();
    message.SmimeAttachSignatureBy(signer);

    SmtpClient.SendSsl(
        message,
        "smtp.gmail.com",
        465,
        "sender@gmail.com",
        "password",
        SaslMechanism.Login);
}
```

How can I send mails with the correct signature?

Comment: could you try `message.From.Email = "sender@gmail.com"`, I suspect that assigning with `new Address(...)` may fill the name property of the from header, which is not part of the actual sender later.

Comment: Same behavior either way

Comment: your code appears to match their sample just fine. positive that the certificate matches 100% ? is it a personal cert on just the mail address, or a wildcard on the sender's domain?

Comment: positive that the certificate matches what? - I just generated it with openssl